# Removing entry from begginng of $PATH

Tags: path, zsh, iterm2, zshrc

In my .zshrc file I added: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` after removing this from the file my path still starts with /usr/local/bin

How can I permanently remove this entry from my path?

Also know when I try to open a file with the open command I get this error:

LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Users/m/.zshrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zsh process reads .zshrc on startup only. Exit and re-login to restart zsh process. Or run the following command-line on the current zsh:

```
% export PATH="${PATH#/usr/local/bin:}"
```

Comment: Best to log out and log in again. The `exec` solution is going to inherit the old value of `PATH` that contains `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Oops... Yes, you are right. Thanks! I'll correct my my error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't let any random sysadmin determine your PATH; you always set your PATH to the one you need in your shell startup file.

Start out with

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

and augment with

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

as desired. That way you are in full control over the sequence and contents and can easily modify the sequence by rearranging lines.